# when to use intersect in a query

Tags: sql, intersect

i am a bit comfused about when do i have to use intersect in sql.The example that i am given is the following:

I have two tables:

```
 MovieStar(name, address, gender, birthdate)
 MovieExec(name, address, cert#, netWorth)
```

The example asks to find the name and address of all female actors who also are a movie executor and have networth over 10000000.The solution of the example in the book is the following:

```
(SELECT name, address
 FROM MovieStar
 WHERE gender = 'F')
   INTERSECT
 (SELECT name, address
  FROM MovieExec
  WHERE netWorth > 10000000);
```

So my problem is why i have to use INTERSECT while i could use the "AND" operator like:

```
SELECT name, address
FROM MovieStar, MovieExec
WHERE gender = 'F' AND netWorth > 10000000
```

Is there any tricky way to figure out when is better to use INTERSECT or "AND"?

Comment: Do you know that `FROM MovieStar, MovieExec` is CROSS JOIN (cartesian product)?

Comment: No sorry, i don't have that information.

Comment: The only tricky way is execution plan and statistics, 2 queries may be equivalent in result but the way they get it may vary. So always compare execution plan, time and resource needed to achieve what you want.

Comment: Basically FROM MovieStar, MovieExec means that you will get NxM records in result. Run `SELECT name, address
FROM MovieStar, MovieExec` and see how many records you get. You should avoid this.

Comment: Thank you for your time, i will try more examples to compare with :)

Comment: The thing is that this is an example from a book so i dont actually have a real database to see what happens, so maybe i should try a fuctional example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `INTERSECT` when it suits you and you get correct results. Second always compare execution plan and statistics, because the way you get result may vary.

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ee8dd/2/0)**

1)

```
 SELECT name, address
 FROM MovieStar
 WHERE gender = 'F'
 INTERSECT
 SELECT name, address
 FROM MovieExec
 WHERE netWorth > 10000000;
```

It means take name and addresses from MovieStar where gender is 'F',
take name and address from MovieExec where networth > 100000 and find records which are in both sets.

2)

```
SELECT ms.name, ms.address
FROM MovieStar AS ms, MovieExec AS me
WHERE gender = 'F' AND netWorth > 10000000
```

It means that you generate `CROSS JOIN` Cartesian Product(MxN records) and then take only records where gender = 'F' AND netWorth > 10000000

I guess that the first approach will returns result faster and use less memory(but Query Optimizer can do a lot).

When you should use `INTERSECT`:

- you want to get intersection of both sets and you cannot JOIN them explicitly

Comment: I think i understand, so with the first solution i would get only the records which are both female and networth > 1000000 but in the second one i will get both records of females and records of networth > 10000000.Thank you!

Comment: @ZisisDiamantis See m updated answer and check sqlfiddle example. In both cases you will get female and networth > 1000000 but in the second you will get the same answer multiple times, it's how CROSS JOIN works, if you don't want this you need to use `SELECT DISTINCT ms.name, ms.address`